# Adding pdf as a resource in .qrc

Tags: c++, qt, pdf, resources

I need to add a pdf file to my resource folder, which I can open from the application with the click of a button (kind of like a Help file).

So my confusions are:

1. How exactly do I add the pdf to my resources?
2. What path should I use to direct to the pdf?

> QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("/Resource Files/Help.pdf"));

Comment: The resource system is documented here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/resources.html But I should point out that on Windows and Linux there's no guarantee that a PDF viewer will be installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add the resource file into your project, right click on the project in the Projects pane and click `Add New...` and then `Qt>Qt Resource file`, enter a name for it and after finishing something is added to your .pro file like :

```
RESOURCES = myResource.qrc
```

Once added into the pro file, a separate .qrc file will be added into your Qt project with which you can double click and add your desired resources like icons, translation files etc. Open the resource file and add your pdf file there.

To open the pdf file from resources, you should first copy it to some location for example in the application directory path :

```
QFile HelpFile("qrc:/myFile.pdf");;
HelpFile.copy(qApp->applicationDirPath().append("/myFile.pdf"));
```

Next you can open the pdf file by :

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl::fromLocalFile(qApp->applicationDirPath().append("/myFile.pdf")));
```

Comment: And just an FYI for others, you might want to print `qApp->applicationDirPath()` to ensure whether your file is in the same location as the app expects it to be. Mine wasn't...